# Continuous Query Notification to Amazon SNS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, cx-oracle

I am thinking of using the Continuous Query Notification service from cx_Oracle in Python to know when a table is updated or inserted. I would like to know how the output of the CQN can be published as a topic to Amazon SNS.To reframe the question, how to send data to SNS from Python via CQN?

Comment: If you are enabling it in cx_Oracle, then the callback will be to a Python function, so the question becomes: 'can you send data to SNS from Python?'  PS, don't forget to plan to upgrade to [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

Comment: if you have an option to use, use aws rds for oracle and enable rds event notification for DB.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra I did look up on that, but the event notification types are not on table or schema level changes. They are at DB instance level. But please do let know if I have may have missed any sites on the same.

Comment: Yes RDS event notification are not for table/schema level.SInce i havent tried it yet, i cannot answer specific answer, but i did find options which may help you 1) Monitor RDS logs and set up cloudwatch alarms to get notification (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.html) 2) Monitoring RDS API calls for insert/update using cloudtrail and setup sns (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html) 3) Monitoring Oracle Database Activity Streams (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/DBActivityStreams.html)